# SQL how to merge select statement

Tags: sql, oracle

i got a question this is what i have

```
SQL> desc trktripleg
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------

 T#                                        NOT NULL NUMBER(10)
 LEG#                                      NOT NULL NUMBER(2)
 DEPARTURE                                 NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)
 DESTINATION                               NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)
```

I tried do the following

```
SQL> select destination,departure from trktripleg where T#=15;

DESTINATION                    DEPARTURE
------------------------------ ------------------------------
Adelaide                       Melbourne
Melbourne                      Sydney
```

How do i make it this way...

```
SOURCE     DESTINATION   DESTINATION2

Adelaide   Melbourne    Sydney
```

Assume if there only 1 destination

```
SQL> select destination,departure from trktripleg where T#=11;

DESTINATION                    DEPARTURE
------------------------------ ------------------------------
Sydney                         Melbourne


SOURCE     DESTINATION   DESTINATION2

Adelaide   Melbourne
```

I am doing view now as like i provide the T# , it will display the source destination depature

Some raw insert data..

```
INSERT INTO TRKTRIPLEG VALUES(11, 1, 'Melbourne', 'Sydney');

INSERT INTO TRKTRIPLEG VALUES(15, 1, 'Sydney', 'Melbourne');
INSERT INTO TRKTRIPLEG VALUES(15, 2, 'Melbourne', 'Adelaide');
```

Thanks for all help. I am using oracle sql.

Comment: :Can you please tell me what is the relation between the three rows mentioned in the last .How can we relate them ,because there will be many other records in the table.I know T#=15 will be the same ticket ,but how can we relate T#11 with T#15.

Comment: @GauravSoni , T#15 is a trip with 2 leg, T#11 is a trip with 1 leg. thus T#15 will have Source, Destination, Destination 2, whileas T#11 will have Source, Destination, Destination 2 (Blank)

Comment: :There will be max of two lags ?

Comment: That table structure has been showing up several times a day for some time now. I wonder where this is being used as training material and why all the students turn here to solve their problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your schema correctly you can do this

```
 SELECT   t1.departure AS Source,
         t1.destination AS Destination1,
         t2.destination AS Destination2
  FROM      trktripleg t1
         LEFT OUTER JOIN
            trktripleg t2
         ON t2.T# = t1.T# AND t2.LEG# = 2
 WHERE   t1.LEG# = 1;
```

[**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7bf68/7)

Comment: :+1 for a better solution .

Comment: Why's it better? Assuming the table is properly indexed this solution requires an index range scan and an index unique scan as opposed to one index range scan and a window sort. The only way to be sure of which is "better" is to test it.

Comment: @Ben:It is better than me , i have tested it and checked the execution plan .

Answer (score 2):

```
create table trktripleg
(
T#                                         NUMBER(10)NOT NULL
 ,LEG#                                       NUMBER(2) NOT NULL
 ,DEPARTURE                                  VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL
 ,DESTINATION                                VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL
  );

INSERT INTO TRKTRIPLEG VALUES(11, 1, 'Melbourne', 'Sydney');

INSERT INTO TRKTRIPLEG VALUES(15, 1, 'Sydney', 'Melbourne');
INSERT INTO TRKTRIPLEG VALUES(15, 2, 'Melbourne', 'Adelaide');

SELECT DEPARTURE
      ,DESTINATION
      ,DESTINATION_2
FROM
(
SELECT DEPARTURE
      ,DESTINATION
      ,LEAD(DESTINATION, 1, NULL) 
              OVER (partition by T# ORDER BY LEG#) DESTINATION_2
      ,LEG#
FROM trktripleg
)
WHERE LEG#=1
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5b27c/11

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this..

```
select 
    t,
    MAX(source),
    max(destination),
    max(destination2)
from
(
    select t, departure as source, DESTINATION ,null as destination2 from yourtable where LEG = 1
    union all
    select t, null, null, destination from yourtable where LEG =2 
) p
group by t
```

More generically, you can do a pivot based on the `leg` value.